# Simple Modal issues - Multiples, Disappearing Content

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm a jQuery newbie and have rigged Simple Modal to allow me to have more than one modal on a page by doing this in my script:

`$('input.basic, a.basic').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next('.basicModalContent').modal();
        });`

here's my HTML:

```
    <a class="basic linkHeading" href="#">Link Heading</a>

 <div class="basicModalContent" style="display: none;">
    <h1>This Resource Requires Login</h1>
    <a href="#" class="simplemodal-close" title="Close">Cancel</a></p>
</div><!--basicModal-->
```

The issue I'm running into is everything works fine on first click & close. The second click launches the modal, but all the content is gone from inside the box.

see this link for the bug in action: http://blanksky.com/test/ebenefits21/modal.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like:

Links:

```
<a href="#" class="basic" id="link-1">link1</a>
<a href="#" class="basic" id="link-2">link2</a>
<a href="#" class="basic" id="link-3">link3</a>
```

Hidden content (via CSS or inline style)

```
<div id="link-1-content" style="display:none">
<p>content</p>
</div>
<div id="link-2-content" style="display:none">
<p>content</p>
</div>
<div id="link-3-content" style="display:none">
<p>content</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#basic-modal input.basic, #basic-modal a.basic').click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var content = '#' + this.id + '-content';
              $(content).modal();
      });
});
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: this is perfect, thanks so much eric (your customer support is the BEST!!)

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the dialog, jQuery changes the position of the div in the DOM, then wanting to locate it with "`$(this).next(...)`", you can not do. You should have some ID or a reference to locate otherwise.

**EDIT:**
Well, you have me thinking a little echo. I hope it is useful the code that I'm going through. I'm not tested:

```
$('input.basic, a.basic').click(function (e) 
{ 
   e.preventDefault(); 
   var el = "";

   if($(this).data("xid")!=undefined)
   {
      el = $($(this).data("xid"));
   }
   else
   {
     var xid = "xid_" + ((new Date()).getTime());
     el = $(this).next('.basicModalContent');
     $(this).data("xid", xid);
     if (el.lenght>0)
       el.attr("id", xid);
   }

   if (el.lenght>0)
   {
     el.modal();
   }
});
```

Comment: the page is pulling dynamic content, so i have no way of knowing how many modal links there could be, or how to reference them.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that requires less markup is to use a single modal "window." See the following example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Simple Modal Demo</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="simplemodal.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
     $('.loginRequired').bind('click',
      function() {
       $('#clickedLink').html(this.id);
       $('#modalWindow').modal();
       return false;
      }
     );
    }
  );
 </script>

 <style>
  #simplemodal-container { display: none; }
  #simplemodal-overlay { background: #000; opacity: 0.4; }
  #modalWindow {
   background: #FFF;
   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 100px;
   opacity: 1.0;
   padding: 10px;
   position: relative;
   width: 220px;
   z-index: 1010;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <p><a href="http://example.com/" id="link1" class="loginRequired">Login Required Link</a></p>
 <p><a href="http://example.com/" id="link2" class="loginRequired">Login Required Link</a></p>
 <p><a href="http://example.com/" id="link3" class="loginRequired">Login Required Link</a></p>
 <p><a href="http://example.com/">http://example.com/</a></p>

 <div id="simplemodal-container">
  <div id="modalWindow">
   <p>Sorry, you must login to click <b id="clickedLink">unknown</b>.</p>
   <p><a href="#" class="simplemodal-close">Cancel</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```