# JQuery Simple Modal OSX Multiple dialogs

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

HI,

I'm planning to use the jquery Simple modal for login and registration on my project site. i tried to have  2 modals as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662226/simple-modal-issues-multiples-disappearing-content/1666144). but im still unable to make it work. here is my code

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var OSX = {
    container: null,
    init: function () {
        $("a.osx").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 

            $(this.id + "_osx-modal-content").modal({
                overlayId: this.id+'_osx-overlay',
                containerId: this.id+'_osx-container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: OSX.open,
                onClose: OSX.close
            });
        });
    },
    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $("#osx-modal-content", self.container).show();
            var title = $("#osx-modal-title", self.container);
            title.show();
            d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var h = $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).height()
                        + title.height()
                        + 20; // padding
                    d.container.animate(
                        {height: h}, 
                        200,
                        function () {
                            $("div.close", self.container).show();
                            $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).show();
                        }
                    );
                }, 300);
            });
        })
    },
    close: function (d) {
        var self = this; // this = SimpleModal object
        d.container.animate(
            {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
            500,
            function () {
                self.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            }
        );
    }
};

OSX.init();
```

I guess its something to do with the open: function part, anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem? If you are using it on a ASP.NET site, make sure to use the appendTo: 'form' option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I make out to modal window by creating and 2 object 1 is osx and other is rosx thats it !!!!

you can mail me @ miliwebdeveloper27@gmail.com for further assistance :) Happy to help always...

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var OSX = {
    container: null,
    init: function () {
        $("input.osx, a.osx").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 

            $("#osx-modal-content").modal({
                overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                containerId: 'osx-container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: OSX.open,
                onClose: OSX.close
            });             
        });
            $("input.rosx, a.rosx").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 

            $("#osx-modal2-content").modal({
                overlayId: 'osx-overlay',
                containerId: 'osx-container',
                closeHTML: null,
                minHeight: 80,
                opacity: 65, 
                position: ['0',],
                overlayClose: true,
                onOpen: OSX.open,
                onClose: OSX.close
            });

        });
    },
    open: function (d) {
        var self = this;
        self.container = d.container[0];
        d.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
            $("#osx-modal-content", self.container).show();
            $("#osx-modal2-content", self.container).show();
            var title = $("#osx-modal-title", self.container);
            title.show();
            d.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var h = $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).height()
                        + title.height()
                        + 20; // padding
                    d.container.animate(
                        {height: h}, 
                        200,
                        function () {
                            $("div.close", self.container).show();
                            $("#osx-modal-data", self.container).show();
                        }
                    );
                }, 300);
            });
        })
    },
    close: function (d) {
        var self = this; // this = SimpleModal object
        d.container.animate(
            {top:"-" + (d.container.height() + 20)},
            500,
            function () {
                self.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            }
        );
    }
};
OSX.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

duplicate

> osx.js into -> osx2.js

and rename

> input.osx2, a.osx -> input.osx2, a.osx2 osx-modal-content ->
>   osx-modal-content2 osx-modal-data -> osx-modal-data2

a little more simplification, i guess?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your answer!! But... Could you please clarify? How does this enable you to have multiple modal dialogs? And, is it still relevant to the TO?